# Is there a flat files JDO implementation?

Tags: filesystems, jdo, flat-file

I have a simple app I'd like to use JDO. But I don't want to use any DB back, just regular file system. Before jdo, I had this class it serializes it object to a file whereas file name is the "primary key". I'd like to be able to do the same thing with JDO. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Reference Implementation for JDO 1.0 used flat files. Look at Apache JDO which ought to contain the original files

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps DataNucleus is a choice for you as it supports different kind of storage backends. The [xml](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/xml/support.html) storage plugin or the embedded database [db4o](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/db4o/support.html) storage plugin might be an option, but both use a single file for all objects instead of one file per object.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I used the JDO 1.0.1 file implementation and worked fine for my simple cases